# Calling a value from a Hash

Tags: ruby, hash

I want this:

```
class Employees
    def initialize
        attr_accessor :first_name, :last_name, :class
    end

    person = Hash.new()
    person["Lauree Brown"] = "Terminated"
    person["Christie Gregour"] = "Active Employee"
    person["Ryan Dunn"] = "Active Employee"
```

to return the names of the employees with the employee status. Do I just call the Hash, or do I have to specifically call the employees? This is the full code:

```
class Employees
    def initialize
        attr_accessor :first_name, :last_name, :class
    end

    person = Hash.new()
    person["Lauree Brown"] = "Terminated"
    person["Christie Gregour"] = "Active Employee"
    person["Ryan Dunn"] = "Active Employee"

    if person = "Terminated"
        puts "#{} is a terminated employee."
    else
        puts "#{} is an active employee."
    end
end
```

As of right now, it returns this:

```
  is terminated employee.
=> nil
```

Comment: There's a whole lot of confusion going on here, as this is barely Ruby code and certainly wouldn't work as intended. `"#{}"` is always going to display nothing.

Comment: Not exactly sure where to start but I think you have the whole concept of Objects and Classes wrong. To fix this it would require a reasonable rewrite and in doing so we would be doing your work for you.

Comment: Fair enough, I'll try again and edit it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this code.

```
person = Hash.new()
person["Lauree Brown"] = "Terminated"
person["Christie Gregour"] = "Active Employee"
person["Ryan Dunn"] = "Active Employee"

person.each do |key, value|
  if value == "Terminated"
    puts "#{key} is a terminated employee."
  else
    puts "#{key} is an active employee."
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's an attempt at fixing it and making it more Ruby-like:

```
class Employee
  attr_accessor :first_name, :last_name, :status

  def initialize(first_name, last_name, status)
    @first_name = first_name
    @last_name = last_name
    @status = status
  end

  def to_s
    "%s %s is an %s Employee" % [
      first_name,
      last_name,
      status
    ]
  end
end

people = [ ]

people << Employee.new('Lauree', 'Brown', 'Terminated')
people << Employee.new('Christie', 'Gregour', 'Active')
people << Employee.new('Ryan', 'Dunn', 'Active')

people.each do |person|
  puts person.to_s
end
```

It's unclear why you declared a hash, or why you were using `attr_accessor` inside `initialize`, a place it won't even work, it's not an instance method.

It's also worth noting to pay particular attention to `=` meaning *assignment* and `==` meaning *comparison*. In your example you were assigning, so the first condition would always trigger, and would also over-write any prior data. This was probably not your intent.

Comment: I don't come from a Ruby background, I'm just learning.

I was under the impression that hashes are used to make a list of values

Comment: Hashes are great for storing unordered data that is accessed by some sort of key, string, number or otherwise. Arrays are better for ordered data, or where they are not necessarily keyed. Think of a Hash as a "dictionary" or a lookup table, like `{ one: 1, two: 2 }` for converting between words and values.

Comment: Thank you that's very insightful.